# Django: Split tests across multiple files, but share same database?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am using Django 1.8. I have been writing tests for my Django API in one long file called `test_api.py`. The structure of the file has been as follows:

```
def setUpModule():
  management.call_command('loaddata', 'frontend/fixtures/data.json',
                        verbosity=0)
  management.call_command('my_custom_command')

def tearDownModule():
  management.call_command('flush', verbosity=0, interactive=False)


class TestAPIBNFViews(TestCase):
  def test_api_view_list_all(self):
    url = '/api/1.0/bnf_code'
    # do testing

def test_api_view_query(self):
    # more testint
```

The fixtures and management command being loaded once before all the tests run, and so far this has worked great.

Now however the file is getting long and unwieldy, and I want to split it into multiple files. I've created multiple files called `test_list` and `test_query` and given each a `setUpModule` section as above.

However, firstly this isn't DRY, and secondly when I run `python manage.py test`, lots of the tests fail with duplicate foreign key errors like:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "frontend_sha_id" already exists
```

I guess this isn't surprising, since the tests are trying to create the test database multiple times.

However, if I remove `setUpModule` from all but the first test (listed alphabetically by filename), the other tests fail because they can't see any data.

How can I run `setUpModule` once, before all the tests run, and still keep the tests in separate files for convenience?

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: in each file before running database creation you may check if it not already exist.

Comment: I guess I could have one file called `test_all.py` and I could import everything else as a module... would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a global `setUpModule` for both test classes, you can alternatively use `setUpTestData` once at each `TestCase` class. From [Django documentation: Testing tools](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData):

> The class-level atomic block ... allows the creation of initial data at the class level, once for the whole `TestCase`.

Comment: Wouldn't that still leave me with the same problem, of having to have everything in one very long file?

Comment: You can define `setUpTestData` once at each class (that would be once per file I suppose unless you have more than one class per file). You can then have this function call another function in one of the n test files that indeed actually sets up data to avoid DRY.

Comment: Thanks! Although then won't I just end up with the same errors, about the database already existing....?

Comment: Welcome! I believe not, this is how I do it although in one file with multiple classes. It shouldn't be too difficult to give it a try, please let me know too!

Comment: thanks, I tried this but it just makes my tests hang forever, for some reason.

Comment: Have you debugged your tests to trace what's being executed?